# Serial port reading - Error : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION - C [rxtxSerial.dll+0x5b00]

Tags: java, java-8, serial-port, rxtx, com-port

Currently I'm trying to read serial port. Working fine in Linux. But facing error in Windows machine.

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15996643) to read serial port and Downloaded RXTX library from [here](http://fizzed.com/oss/rxtx-for-java) for windows machine (JAR + DLL file).

**OS** : Windows 10 with 64bit

**Java jre** : Jre 1.8.0_261 VERSION.

Exception throws when read through input stream.

**Error log :**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180005b00, pid=4508, tid=0x0000000000002b90
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_261-b12) (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.261-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x5b00]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\serialport\hs_err_pid4508.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Suggessions will helpful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR: Do not use 1.8.0_261 use 1.8.0_251 instead**

I tried to reproduce this error with 1.8.0_181, 1.8.0_251 and 1.8.0_261 using Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.1082).

I could only reproduce this error with Jre 1.8.0_261. u181 and u251 worked fine for me. I would suggest to use java 8 u251 from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html .

Answer (score 1):

Serial port depending parts of the application I am working on failed today after the java update from 1.8.0_241 to 1.8.0_271. I think the problem could be the switch from Visual Studio 2010 to 2017 which Java 8 is build with now.

> New Features:
>
> > ➜ JDK/JRE Runtime Windows Visual Studio Library (DLL) Dependency Changes

[Java 1.8.0_261 Release Notes](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u261-relnotes.html)

Update: I was on an quite old version(2017) of [jssc(Java Simple Serial Connector)](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector). Unfortunately the original has no updates since a while. But I found a  [fork on GitHub](https://github.com/java-native/jssc) which continues development. Whith the forked version I had no further issues!

Answer (score 0):

I tested RXTX with the newer Java 8u281 release from 19 Jan. 2021 but it also crashes.

However AdoptOpenJDK 8u282 is working smoothly without any errors with the serial communication using RXTX and looks like it fully compatible with Oracle JDK!!! [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8)